# Logcat android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite

sorry if this is a question that many other ask.. but i checked their question but i can't find the solution (sorry noobs here..)

here is my logcat

```
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: translate: , while compiling: SELECT _id,kata_indo,kata_toraja FROM translate WHERE kata_indo = 'anjing' ORDER BY kata_indo
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at kamus.indonesia.toraja.TranslateIndonesia.trans(TranslateIndonesia.java:107)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at kamus.indonesia.toraja.TranslateIndonesia$1.onClick(TranslateIndonesia.java:45)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-13 00:38:34.267: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my the class that the error occured `translateindonesia.java`

```
package kamus.indonesia.toraja;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TranslateIndonesia extends Activity {

    Button translate, back;
    EditText bhsIndonesia, bhsToraja;
    String translateIndonesia;
    public Cursor mCursor;
    public DbHelper helper;
    public SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translateindonesia);

        helper = new DbHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        translate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTerjemahkanIndonesia);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        bhsIndonesia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIndonesia);
        bhsToraja = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextToraja);

        translate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String search = bhsIndonesia.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                if (search.contains(" ")){
                    parsing ();
                }
                else{
                    trans ();
                }

            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent menu = new Intent(TranslateIndonesia.this,MainActivity.class);
                menu.putExtra("pesan", "From TranslateIndonesia Menu");
                startActivity(menu);
            }
        });
    }

    public void parsing (){
        String search = bhsIndonesia.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String temp[] = search.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        String tempS[] = search.split("[a-zA-Z]+");
        Boolean char1 = search.substring(0, 1).matches("[a-zA-Z]");
        bhsToraja.setText("");

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            try{
                db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOWER(kata_indo) as kata_indo, LOWER (kata_toraja) as kata_toraja FROM translate WHERE Lower(kata_indo) = ?", new String[]{temp[i]});
                int countRow = cursor.getCount();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String specialChar = "";
                if(tempS.length > i){
                    specialChar = tempS[i];
                }
                if(!char1){
                    if(countRow > 0){
                        bhsToraja.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kata_toraja")) + specialChar);
                    } else {
                        bhsToraja.append(temp[i] + specialChar);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(countRow > 0){
                        bhsToraja.append(specialChar + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kata_toraja")));
                    } else {
                        bhsToraja.append(specialChar + temp[i]);
                    }
                }
                //
            }
            catch(SQLiteConstraintException ex){
                bhsToraja.setText(ex.toString());
            }
        }
        if(tempS.length > 0 && tempS.length > temp.length){
            bhsToraja.append(tempS[tempS.length-1]);
        }
    }

    public void trans(){
        String result = "";
        String search = bhsIndonesia.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,kata_indo,kata_toraja FROM translate " + "WHERE kata_indo = '"+search+"' ORDER BY kata_indo",null);
        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
            result = mCursor.getString(2);
            for(;!mCursor.isAfterLast();mCursor.moveToNext()){
                result = mCursor.getString(2);
            }
        }
        if(result.equals("")){
            result = "Kata tidak ditemukan";
        }
        bhsToraja.setText(result);
    }
//end   

}
```

do i need to edit some lines or my DB isn't existed even thou i put one in assets folder?

really appreciate your help.. thanks before..

this is the `DBHelper.java`

```
package kamus.indonesia.toraja;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbkamus.sqlite";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static File DATABASE_FILE;
    private boolean mInvalidDatabaseFile = false;
    private boolean mIsUpgraded = false;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mOpenConnections = 0;
    private static DbHelper mInstance;

    synchronized static public DbHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;

    }

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try{
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            if (db != null){
                db.close();
            }
            DATABASE_FILE = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
            if (mInvalidDatabaseFile){
                copyDatabase();
            }
            if(mIsUpgraded){
                doUpgrade();
            }
        }catch (SQLiteException e){

        }finally {
            if(db != null && db.isOpen()){
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        mInvalidDatabaseFile = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int old_version, int new_version){
        mInvalidDatabaseFile = true;
        mIsUpgraded = true;
    }
    private void doUpgrade(){

    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onOpen(db);
        mOpenConnections++;
        if(!db.isReadOnly()){
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        mOpenConnections--;
        if(mOpenConnections == 0){
            super.close();
        }
    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
        AssetManager assetManager = mContext.getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try{
            in = assetManager.open(DATABASE_NAME);
            out = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_NAME);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } catch(IOException e){

        }finally{
            if(in != null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                }catch(IOException e){}
            }
            if(out != null){
                try{
                    out.close();
                }catch(IOException e){}
            }
        }
        setDatabaseVersion();
        mInvalidDatabaseFile = false;

    }

    private void setDatabaseVersion(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try{
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = " + VERSION);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){

        }finally{
            if(db != null && db.isOpen()){
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAll(){
        return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, kata_indo, kata_toraja from translate ORDER BY _id ASC", null));
    }

    public void insertKey(String indo, String toraja){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("kata_indo", indo);
        cv.put("kata_toraja", toraja);
        getWritableDatabase().insert("translate","kata_indo", cv);
    }

    public void delete(long id){
        getWritableDatabase().delete("translate", KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think your `Activity` is causing any problems because it's a problem of the database not existing, which means it's not getting created (or initialized from the one in the assets folder). What does your DBHelper look like? Specifically the onCreate, since that's where you should create the database.

Comment: Show your database class. Your database is not created.

Comment: @Jakar i added the DbHelper in the question above.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Start your application.
2)Go to ADM monitor
3)find your app => go to data find your databases and delete
4)restart app
////////////////////
initiliaze your dbHelper beforeonCreate(when you declare)

suggestion: Don't make an object and database have the same name.

Comment: sorry for the noob question but can you show me where is it? ^^ the object and database i mean.. ^^

Comment: it is between sdk manager and question mark at toolbox. You don't need to have Sqlitedatabase object in mainactivity, actually you shouldn't. parsing and trans methods should be in dbHelper class.

Comment: so i just need to move the parsing and trans methods to dbhelper class?

Comment: make a seperated dbHelper class which handles everyting about database. I don't suggest you execute your queries or parse data in an activity.This will make your code better and more readable.